# Unable to find "Structures/Graph.php" after installing Structures_Graph of PHP pear on Amazon Linux

Tags: php, pear

I installed pear and found that I have the `Structures_Graph` directory inside pear directory -

```
/home/ec2-user/pear/tests
```

But, I cannot find the `Structures/Graph.php` and `Structures/Graph/Node.php` as mentioned in https://pear.php.net/package/Structures_Graph/docs/latest/li_Structures_Graph.html

I was following this article http://www.codediesel.com/algorithms/building-a-graph-data-structure-in-php/, following which installation of Structures_Graph has to be done with this -

```
pear install Structures_Graph
```

I get -

```
pear/Structures_Graph is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.1
install failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `/home/ec2-user/pear/tests` is your pear directory; you probably have a system-wide pear installation.

Get its location with

```
$ pear config-get php_dir
```